QGIS: Count points directly left/right of line using geometry generator
I have a line layer and a points layer. I am trying to count the points that are within 500 meters directly to one side of my lines.  I have entered the following code into Value   As far as my knowledge extends this should work, but it doesn't, it returns Preview: 0.
'Points counted: '||aggregate(
    layer:='random_points_to_be_counted_986f0158_68af_4040_9d5d_d657b6b32d93',
    aggregate:='count',
    expression:=id,
    filter:=intersects(
make_line(
        make_point(start_point($geometry)),
        make_point(
            x(project(line_interpolate_point($geometry, 0), 500, radians("winkel" + 90))),
            y(project(line_interpolate_point($geometry, 0), 500, radians("winkel" + 90)))
        ),
        make_point(
            x(project(line_interpolate_point($geometry, length($geometry)), 500, radians(180))),
            y(project(line_interpolate_point($geometry, length($geometry)), 500, radians(180)))
        ),
         make_point(end_point($geometry)
        )
    )
,
        geometry(@parent)
    )
)

Both point and line layer are in EPSG 25832.

If you break your expression down and first try to create only the rectangle to the side of the line (in my case using Geometry Generator), you will find that there is an error (in the full expression it causes the expression to fail silently).

Eval Error: Function make_point requires 2-4 arguments

This is because you pass start_point($geometry) to make_point, which is unnecessary. make_point can be omitted here (as it can in the line make_point(end_point($geometry)).
A further issue is that the result of this part of the expression is a LineString (3 sides of your desired rectangle), the red line in the image below.

Therefore, the intersection will only count points that exactly intersect this line.
This can be fixed by wrapping this part of the expression in make_polygon.
Also noteworthy is that you have a lot of redundancy in the way you build your line using make_line. There is no need to find the x and y of the points and then use make_point with them to remake the same point, you already have the points to start with! And line_interpolate_point($geometry, 0) is equivalent to start_point (likewise with end_point).
make_line(
    start_point($geometry),
    project(start_point($geometry), 500, radians("winkel" + 90)),
    project(end_point($geometry), 500, radians("winkel" + 90)),             
    end_point($geometry)
)

With these adaptations, the expression becomes:
'Points counted: '||

aggregate(
    layer:='points',
    aggregate:='count',
    expression:=id,
    filter:=
        intersects(
            make_polygon(
                make_line(
                        start_point($geometry),
                        project(start_point($geometry), 500, radians("winkel" + 90)),
                        project(end_point($geometry), 500, radians("winkel" + 90)),             
                        end_point($geometry)
                    )
            ), 
            geometry(@parent)
        )
)

Having said all that, the expression still does not work. I do not know why, I suspect it may be a bug*.
Another way to approach it is to get the intersection between the points layer as a multipoint and the rectangle and count the number of resulting geometries:
'Points counted: '||

num_geometries(
    intersection(
        make_polygon(
            make_line(
                start_point($geometry),
                project(start_point($geometry), 500, radians("winkel" + 90)),
                project(end_point($geometry), 500, radians("winkel" + 90)),
                end_point($geometry)
            )
        ),      
        aggregate('points', 'collect', $geometry)
    )
)


Preview: 'Points counted: 28'

The blue points here represent the intersection.

To simplify it further, you could use a single_sided_buffer, but this relies on knowing which way your line is drawn. A positive distance buffers to the left of the line, a negative distance buffers to the right.
'Points counted: '||

num_geometries(
    intersection(
        single_sided_buffer($geometry, -500),
        aggregate('points', 'collect', $geometry)
    )
)


* Reasoning for suspecting it may be a bug:
Testing a simplified version of your expression with buffer works fine, but single_sided_buffer gives an empty geometry.
This works:
aggregate(
    layer:='points',
    aggregate:='count',
    expression:=$id,
    filter:=
        intersects(
            buffer($geometry, 500),
            geometry(@parent)
        )
)

This does not:
aggregate(
    layer:='points',
    aggregate:='count',
    expression:=$id,
    filter:=
        intersects(
            single_sided_buffer($geometry, -500),
            geometry(@parent)
        )
)

Despite there definitely being points within the single_sided_buffer.

Thank you so much for your well thought out and detailed answer.
Although it seems there is a bug, QGIS is flexible enough to offer a work-around, which you very cleverly found.
I also experimented with buffer before posting the question and found that it works however i was not able to edit the additional parameters, in particular to create a flat end.
Nevertheless thank you, this will improve my workflow.

You're welcome. I was rather perplexed why your (fixed) expression did not work. But, testing with the native buffer and single_sided_buffer appears to indicate that something is amiss.
